# How to determine the values of transportation delay blocks and step block in block diagram?

Tags: dc-motor, control-system, matlab, simulink, time

What are the values of transportation delay blocks and step block in this block diagram to get Motor speed Graph for KI = 1.0s−1, KP = 0.3 and time delay = 0.046?

[image: Simulink model of the time-delayed DC motor speed control system]